# Angular reactive forms - prevent refresh on submission

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using reactive forms and I have a simple form to add products.
this is the product interface:

```js
export interface Product {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    storeName: string,
    price: number,
    isRecieved: boolean,
    deliveryDate: Date
}
```

Each time the user click on the 'Add Button' the form is being submitted. Since each time I'm adding an ID to the submitted product I don't want to refresh the page so I could keep the idCounter variable updated. Although I added `event.preventDefault()` after submission, the idCounter is turning to it's start value so I'm guessing the page is being updated. How can I prevent it?

```
<form [formGroup]="addProductForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">
<div>More inputs</div>
<button type="submit" mat-button color="accent" >Add Product</button>
```

countId: number = 1;

```
onSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
if (this.addProductForm.valid) {
  this.addProductForm.value.id = this.countId;
  console.log(this.addProductForm.value)
  this.addProductForm.value.isRecieved = false;
  this.store.dispatch(addProductToList(this.addProductForm.value));
  this.countId++;
  this.addProductForm.reset(this.addProductForm)
  this.router.navigate(['/products']);
}
```

}

Comment: Create a service and store the counter value and whenever you need just fetch it from there using observable(), counter resets because of router.navigate

Comment: Glad to know it worked.. you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service and use BehaviorSubject as shown below and everytime on ngOnInit() you can fetch the value via asObservable():

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
    private counterId: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0);
    counterIdStatus = this.counterId.asObservable();

    updateCounterId(id) {
    this.counterId.next(id);
  }
}
```

**Component.ts:**

```
constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
  ) { }

.....

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.userService.counterIdStatus.subscribe(data => this.countId = data);
} 

onSubmit() {
if (this.addProductForm.valid) {
  this.addProductForm.value.id = this.countId;
  console.log(this.addProductForm.value)
  this.addProductForm.value.isRecieved = false;
  this.store.dispatch(addProductToList(this.addProductForm.value));
  this.countId++;
  this.userService.updateCounterId(this.countId);
  this.addProductForm.reset(this.addProductForm)
  this.router.navigate(['/products']);
}
```